# How do I remove Google Fonts from a parent theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, fonts

I'm using the theme Pixgraphy and created a child theme. Because of recent changes concerning data protection in the EU, I now want to load Google Fonts locally.

The parent theme includes the Google Fonts like this:

**wp-content/themes/pixgraphy/inc/settings/pixgraphy-functions.php**

```
/********* Adding Multiple Fonts ********************/
    $pixgraphy_googlefont = array();
    array_push( $pixgraphy_googlefont, 'Open+Sans:400,400italic,600');
    array_push( $pixgraphy_googlefont, 'Merriweather:400');
    $pixgraphy_googlefonts = implode("|", $pixgraphy_googlefont);
    wp_register_style( 'pixgraphy_google_fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$pixgraphy_googlefonts);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pixgraphy_google_fonts' );
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
```

Now in the **functions.php** of the child theme, I did this:

```
function remove_google_fonts_stylesheet() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'pixgraphy_google_fonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_google_fonts_stylesheet', 100 );
```

From what I read everywhere, this should work. But it doesn't, the Google Fonts are still loaded. This is the website: http://werner-mueller-fotografie.de/

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try to deregister the style within your function since it has been register in the parent theme function.

Try:

```
function remove_google_fonts_stylesheet() {
     wp_dequeue_style( 'pixgraphy_google_fonts' );
     wp_deregister_style('pixgraphy_google_fonts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_google_fonts_stylesheet', 100 );
```